# Color coding SQL Server 2008 databases

Tags: sql-server-2008

I often have multiple databases open in SQL Server 2008. Often they are prod, dev, and dr. It is annoying because each window says something generic like SQLQuery1.sql... (sa(200))*. So I have to hover over the tab and make sure I am in the correct window.

Is there a way to color code each window, or in some way to make it instantly knowable which database or server I am in?

Jonathan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can color-code connections in SQL 2008, by modified the properties of the registered server. There is a "Use Custom Color" option on the Connection Properties tab.

See this cool tutorial video by [the Midnight DBA](http://midnightdba.itbookworm.com/KatmaiCoolSSMSFeatures/KatmaiCoolSSMSFeatures.html)

Comment: You can use the SQL 2008 management studio to connect to and manage SQL 2005 servers, so you may be able to use it now!

Comment: You might be able to get by with 2008 SSMS Express, too...which is free.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about changing the colors, but I got tired of the small tab truncating the window name.  As a result I run them as windows, so the entire DB name shows in the window's frame.

I have 2005 (shouldn't be that different than 2008) and this is where I made the change:

```
tools - options:
    environment
        general
            MDI Environment
```